# How to copy rows with a specific value in a column to another sheet?

Tags: excel, row, multiple-columns

I have a list with two columns: A: identifier and B: country. I would like to create a dropdown with a list of countries and use it to choose a country and copy all the rows that have that specific country into a new sheet (without gaps).

For example, if I could UAE from a dropdown, I would like the following list:

```
EJ524848 UAE
EI822533 Serbia
EK025240 BAHAMAS
EI668639 UAE
EK338894 KENYA
JK919347 UAE
```

to output to sheet 2:

```
EJ524848 UAE
EI668639 UAE
JK919347 UAE
```

Comment: Have you considered a [pivot table](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Let's say you put your string to match (for example, `UAE`) in E1.
2. Put this in C1 and fill down column:

   =IF(B1 = $E$1, A1, "")
3. Put this in D1 and fill down column:

   =IF(B1 = $E$1, B1, "")
4. Copy columns C and D.
5. Paste Special... with Values selected.
6. Sort pasted cells to remove blanks.